# Change color of text in dynamic table AngularJS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am working on a web application in which I maintain a **favorites table**. How can I change color of values in HTML table? For example if for a particular column value is less than 0 then display in red and if value id more than 0, display in green. This is the snippet of my code:

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="margin-top: 10px;" id="favoritesTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Symbol</th>
        <th>Stock Price</th>
        <th>Change (Change Percent)</th>
        <th>Volume</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in mylist">
        <td><a ng-click="changeValue(x[0]);getStockDetails()" style="color: blue; cursor: pointer;" data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel">{{x[0]}}</a></td>
        <td>{{x[1]}}</td>
        <td id="changeAndPercent">{{x[2]}} ({{x[3]}}%)</td>
        <td>{{x[4]}}</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="removeFromTable(x[0])"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am storing data in mylist variable in angularJS. I want to check if x[2] is greater than 0 then display it in green color and if it is less than 0 display it in red color.

Things I tried were adding script tag inside table and creating table in JavaScript. When I created table in a JavaScript function then ng-click functions did not work. Please help!

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I have also attached an image of my table --> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple use `ng-class` set to show red color if value is zero

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope, $timeout) {
$scope.data=[{value:0},{value:-1},{value:1}]
});
```

```css
.text-red{
  color:red
}

.arrow-green{
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  
  border-left: 20px solid green;
}
.arrow-red{
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  
  border-left: 20px solid red;
}
  .text-green{
  color:green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<table>

<tr ng-repeat="item in data">
  <td ng-class="{'text-red': item.value <=0,'text-green': item.value >0}">
   My value is {{item.value}}
 <div  ng-class="{'arrow-red': item.value <=0,'arrow-green': item.value >0}"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I also have to append red and green arrows depending on the value. How can I do that with ng-class?